# PowerApps :- Failed to load resource

Tags: authentication, powerapps

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Bearer error=access_denied, error_description=Authentication fail. Ticket id xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.windows.net%2fcommon%2fwsfed, realm=Microsoft.CRM'.)

Comment: Please provide some context for the issue you're facing, including the steps to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

If you've added sample app and it has Office365 Users or similar connector - just try re-create the datasource with the same name and it will fix the issue.